# What are good combinations of Scala + Web framework + Javascript framework?

Tags: javascript, scala, extjs, lift

I have been trying for a long time to study something different to build my so planned web project (lol) and I went through some Django and Rails but gave up, mainly because of the language. I work with Java, but don't want to develop using JSP/JSF/Servlet...
Reading about Scala raised again my interest in Studying web technologies to build my project.

To be honest, I never worked with javascript frameworks and therefore json.

I went through a long list of Scala web frameworks (mainly Lift, Scalatra, Bowler, Scalate, Play!....) and then I realized I would need some javascript technology to build the pages.
Frankly, I don't know if I am willing to build from scratch components, when I could simply use something like Extjs, so I decided to search for javascript frameworks.

So, I went down one level in the search tree (Scala -> [web framework] -> [javascript framework]) and realized I am screwed.

I need to choose something to learn, and I would like to choose something useful, even if has commercial license like Extjs.

When I decided to study Lift, I could see some problems in Lift+Extjs integration, mainly because they don't provide this integration, and suggest you to implement your own (don't know how much work this would be).

Then I read about Lift + Cappuccino, but instantly cried blood after realizing the learning curve of Scala + Lift + Cappuccino... but if it really worths, I could do it...

So, my question is, what are the possible good combinations of Scala web frameworks and javascript frameworks?

I am really stuck in this question, and fed up of simply searching about frameworks just trying to guess which is the best and more flexible so I wont waste my time with future huge achitectural problems.

ps: one of my main concern about the javascript framework is the components. For instance, I need a good tree implementation, but I couldn't build one myselft (I could see there is tree components in Extjs, Cappuccino, jQuery and others....).

ps2: thank you for the suggestions! Question closed :-(

ps3: I decided to use Play/jQuery/Coffeescript/Backbone.

Answer (score 1):

Try [Scala + Wicket](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2104724/your-experience-with-scalawicket)

When it comes to JavaScript and Wicket, I've had good results wrapping YUI.  Here's a blog post on how to do it in Java, you can very easily do the same in Scala: [YUI Autocomplete Tutorial](http://ptrthomas.wordpress.com/2009/08/12/wicket-tutorial-yui-autocomplete-using-json-and-ajax/)

There are libraries that wrap JavaScript widgets for Wicket, such as [WiQuery](http://code.google.com/p/wiquery/) which is probably all that you need.

Keep in mind that one of the selling points of Wicket is that for typical Ajax behaviors (loading / updating a given div etc.) you can do it in Java (or Scala) without writing any JavaScript code.